# Core Data reaching storage limits

Tags: core-data, storage

I need to know how to react when I want to save data under Core Data and the system is reaching limits in terms of storage capacity.

- How do I know that I do not have much storage left?
- How do I know that I do not have enough space to store what I want to store?
- How do I handle errors (what are they?) in case there are?

I have used Core Data quite a lot, but mainly for read only data or for storing small quantities.

Any suggestion on a good document or tutorial on the subject would be welcome.
I do not need any general introduction on Core Data though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To check disk-space:

```
      NSDictionary* fileAttribs = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] attributesOfFileSystemForPath:@"/" error:&error];
      unsigned long long freeSpace = [[fileAttribs objectForKey:NSFileSystemFreeSize] longLongValue];
      NSLog(@"free space: %dGB", (int)(freeSpace / 1073741824)); //Note you just have to change the value here to get KB, MB, GB, TB etc...
```

And the Cocoa domain error codes for file read/write are:

```
NSFileNoSuchFileError = 4
NSFileLockingError = 255
NSFileReadUnknownError = 256
NSFileReadNoPermissionError = 257
NSFileReadInvalidFileNameError = 258
NSFileReadCorruptFileError = 259
NSFileReadNoSuchFileError = 260
NSFileReadInapplicableStringEncodingError = 261
NSFileReadUnsupportedSchemeError = 262
NSFileReadTooLargeError = 263
NSFileReadUnknownStringEncodingError = 264
NSFileWriteUnknownError = 512
NSFileWriteNoPermissionError = 513
NSFileWriteInvalidFileNameError = 514
NSFileWriteFileExistsError = 516
NSFileWriteInapplicableStringEncodingError = 517
NSFileWriteUnsupportedSchemeError = 518
NSFileWriteOutOfSpaceError = 640
NSFileWriteVolumeReadOnlyError = 642
```